# How to set device viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 questions on setting viewport ?

1. Is the meta tag the only way to set viewport? I mean is it possible through JS or some other way?
2. I have a Java app (uses JSP/Struts, etc). So can I set it globally from a single place? If yes, can I override it for a particular page if I need to later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the viewport via meta tags and CSS. 
This article is also a good introduction to viewport property and how you can set it via CSS http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/ and other means.

Comment: Thanks a lot...For setting via CSS, using @-o-viewport; will it work for iPad ?

Comment: I mean for Opera..it is @-o-viewport, but what about iPad ?

Comment: Webkit does not support it yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a [reiszeTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.resizeTo) function that forces the window to change and [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth) for adjusting the viewport width. This [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html) explains how to combine CSS meta tags and JS to adjust the viewport.

Comment: IF you are using JS, write the resize function (with a default width & height) and include the file on every page. Then call it when the dom is ready. If you need to change the width/height on the fly the function will need a method for overriding your default width and height.

Comment: ok..Still waiting for the answers to 2. I have a Java app (uses JSP/Struts, etc). So can I set it globally from a single place? If yes, can I override it for a particular page if I need to later ?